# jqGrid - Custom button in nav bar added multiples times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've added a custom button on my nav bar:

```
function myFunc(){
$("#grid").jqGrid({ 
    datatype: 'json',
    url: 'arquivo.jsp',
    jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, root: 'root'},
    pager: '#paginado',
    rowNum: 10,
    autoencode: true,
    rowList: [10,20,30],        
    emptyrecords: "Não há registros.",
    recordtext: "Registros {0} - {1} de {2}",
    loadtext: "Carregando...",
    pgtext: "Página {0} de {1}",
    height: 250,
    width: 700,
    colNames:['Código','Nome', 'Ativo', 'Data Inclusão','Login','Senha','Confirma Senha','Email','Grupos'],
    colModel:[                                    
        {name:'codigo', width:80, sorttype:"int", editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }},
        {name:'nome', width:120, editable: true, editrules:{required:true}},
        {name:'ativo', width:80, gridview: true, editable: true, edittype:'select', editoptions:{value:{1:'Sim',2:'Não'}}, editrules:{required:true}},     
        {name:'dataInclusao', width:120, sorttype:"date", datefmt: 'd/M/Y', editable: true, editrules:{required:true, date:true}, editoptions: { dataInit: function(el) { setTimeout(function() { $(el).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val(); }, 200); }}},
        {name:'login', width:80, sortable:true, editable: true, editrules:{required:true}},  
        {name:'senha', width:80, sortable:true, editable: true, hidden:true, edittype:'password', editrules:{edithidden:true, required:true, custom:true, custom_func:validaSenha}},
        {name:'confirmaSenha', width:80, sortable:true, editable: true, hidden:true, edittype:'password', editrules:{edithidden:true, required:true}},
        {name:'email', width:150, sortable:true, editable: true, editrules:{required:true, email:true}} 
    ],
    multiselect: true,
    viewrecords: true,    
    editurl:"data?edit=true",
    caption: "Usuários"}
);              
$("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#paginado',{},
    {edit:true,url:"teste?acao=edit",closeAfterEdit:true,reloadAfterSubmit:true, 
        beforeShowForm: function(form) {                
            $('#tr_codigo', form).hide(); 
        }, 
        onClickSubmit: function(params, postdata) {
            validaSenha();
        }
    },
    {add:true,url:"teste?acao=teste",closeAfterAdd:true,reloadAfterSubmit:true, 
        beforeShowForm: function(form) { 
            $('#tr_codigo', form).hide(); 
        }, 
        onClickSubmit: function(params, postdata) {
            validaSenha();
        }
    },
    {del:true,reloadAfterSubmit:true, 
        onclickSubmit: function(url, postdata){
            url.url = 'teste?acao=del';
            return {codigo: $('#grid').getCell(postdata, 'codigo')};
        }
    },
    {search:true},
    {refresh:true}
).navButtonAdd('#paginado',{
    caption:"", 
    buttonicon:"ui-icon-suitcase", 
    onClickButton: function(){ 
        var dados = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');         
    }, 
    position:"last"
});
```

};

but everytime I click on the page that shows my grid, a new button is added as you can see in this image:

[image]

I don't know if my .jsp can be bringing on this problem but I definitely can't find where the problem is. Hope you guys can help me

Thanks in advance,

Lucas.

Comment: This happens when you click _anywhere_ on the page containing your grid? Or does this only happen when clicking in a certain spot?

Comment: It happens everytime I refresh the page but it doesn't happen when I refresh clicking the button on nav bar. It looks like that it's overwriting my grid but the funny thing is that the only part that is added multiple times is the custom button

Comment: Can you show more of your code? I just want to see where you use the `navButtonAdd` function... Maybe the placement is what's causing the issue.

Comment: I edited with the whole code now

Comment: Hmmm.. I see you have your grid setup wrapped in a a function: `myFunc()`... Try moving the grid setup out of the function, so that it's on its own. Also, where you do call `myFunc()`? I'm thinking this has something to do with that function

Comment: But I have a few functions to setup other grids on this file, if I move them out of their functions, how could I specify which one should be created, expanded, etc? Actually this myFunc() is being called on my index.jsp: if the user clicks on a specific config button, myFunc() is called and the grid shows up on another .jsp file that contains the html code (divs, table, tr, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using $('#grid').jqGrid('GridUnload');

Answer (score 0):

There is another thread which talks about same issue. In the newer version the syntax got changed. Might help someone. Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351117/jqgrid-no-such-method-gridunload)

```
$.jgrid.gridUnload("#jqGridId");
```