# JQgrid - no such method gridunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, jqgrid

I am using latest version of jqGrid(4.8.2), and there are some strange:

1. There is no file: grid.custom.js, in folder(or in github)
2. In wiki(http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) that method must be in file grid.custom.js

Finally, in source i can find method: gridUnload : function ( jqGridId ), and it's look similar(but you must call this method like this:

```
$.jgrid.gridUnload('jqGridKoeff');
```

But this situation is really strange. Be careful!

Comment: The changes are described in [the release notes](http://guriddo.net/?p=123585) to Guriddo jqGrid JavaScript 4.8. That changes not exist in [free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).

Answer (score 7):

There is a change in newer versions of the grid. Now you have to call GridUnload functions like the following:

```
$.jgrid.gridUnload(‘#jqGridId’);
```

where jqGridId is the id of the grid